Magento 2 : GraphQL - Generate Customer Token not working
I'm performing the below CURL request in Postman, but it's not working.
curl --location 'http://gravity.freestylelibre.devops:81/graphql' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer fkvb31wfm3xh64k415hldo5eba4qiu4s' \
--header 'store: 37' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=rimu6j4naus2c67jstmsar1j4a; private_content_version=c5ffb5a3f0dae6c381024d34148823e0' \
--data-raw '{"query":"mutation {\r\n  generateCustomerToken(\r\n   email: \"chris.anderson1@abbott.com\"\r\n   password: \"Nilkunj@123\"\r\n  ) {\r\n    token \r\n  }\r\n}","variables":{}}'


Try with below CURL request.
curl --location -g 'http://gravity.freestylelibre.devops:81/graphql' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"query":"mutation {\r\n  generateCustomerToken(\r\n   email: \"chris.anderson1@abbott.com\"\r\n   password: \"Nilkunj@123\"\r\n  ) {\r\n    token \r\n  }\r\n}","variables":{}}'

Don't need to pass Authorization in the CURL request for the generate customer token.

You don't need to pass these headers. I tried your request, but the server is returning a 502 Bad Gateway error. I added the code that should work.
--header 'Authorization: Bearer fkvb31wfm3xh64k415hldo5eba4qiu4s'
--header 'store: 37'

Sample code which work:
curl --location 'http://gravity.freestylelibre.devops:81/graphql' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"query":"mutation {\r\n    generateCustomerToken(\r\n        email: \"chris.anderson1@abbott.com\"\r\n        password: \"Nilkunj@123\"\r\n    ) {\r\n        token\r\n    }\r\n}\r\n","variables":{}}'

